# Unable to download image from the url

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bitmapimage

Hi please help

**Bitmap is null when running on a device but it runs fine when running on Genymotion(Emulator)**

I'm trying to download image from a URL
when i'm running it in Genymotion(Emulator) its running fine and displaying the image,but when i'm running it on a device Bitmap is null.

Below is the code

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}
```

and this is the url

```
url=http://www.hugosys.in/www.nett-torg.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Lighthouse3-300x225.jpg
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use jsoup.jar file for downloading image from server.

For Ex.

```
    String baseUrl = "URL Here";
    try 
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl).get();
        Elements content = doc.select("a");
        Element last = content.last();
        lastEle=last.text();
        String temp="";
        int totalSize;
        //
        while (!a)
        {
            temp = content.get(i).text();
            a=lastEle.equals(temp);
            File f1 = new File(path);

            File f = new File(f1, temp);
            //Log.d("Image path", f+"");    
            tmpUrl = baseUrl + temp;
        //  Log.d("Full URL", tmpUrl);
            if(!f.exists())
            {
                url = new URL(tmpUrl);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();

                FileOutputStream fileOutput=new FileOutputStream(f);

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                int downloadedSize = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                str= "";
                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
                {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Image Available", "Available");
            }
            i++;
        }    
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try loading the bitmap like this:

```
              public  Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String url) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;
                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpResponse response = null;
                    try {
                        response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (response != null) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = null;
                        try {
                            bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        InputStream instream = null;
                        try {
                            instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);

                    }
                    return bitmap;
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code segments which really helps you..

The Files contains Download and set image on image view using ImageLoader.Java
and their is ImageCache maintained for saving time..

[FileCache.java](http://pastebin.com/wfMJzQWh)

[ImageLoader.java](http://pastebin.com/aCVF0vab)

[MemoryCache.java](http://pastebin.com/EK1V52hX)

[Utils.java](http://pastebin.com/EHGqXBkE)

Add Permissions in Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And code to set image on image view is...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Button button;
    private ImageView image;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final String url="http://www.hugosys.in/www.nett-torg.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Lighthouse3-300x225.jpg";
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, image);
            }
        });
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking ur code, i come to know that there is lack of permissions in the manifest thats why it is creating the problem

**Case 1-->**
**When u use ur code in genymotion it works fine since there is no need of read write access in your simulator.**

**Case 2-->**
**When u run in device it needs the proper permisions to store the images in device cache that's y it is not working in device.**

So you have to add two more permissions in the manifest..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope this works, feel free to ask me back...!!!!